# What does the $http.get function do in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a project using AngularJS's MVC structure.

As I am not familiar with those Web application tools, I can't figure out what all those variables do.

I have three files.

app.js has

```
var httpApiConfig = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    }
};
app.constant('httpApiConfig', httpApiConfig)
```

index.php

```
<?php


/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        }
        else
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
        }
    break;

    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" directory.
 * Set the path if it is not in the same directory as this file.
 */
    $system_path = 'system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * directory than the default one you can set its name here. The directory
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server. If you do,
 * use an absolute (full) server path.
 * For more info please see the user guide:
 *
 * https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $application_folder = 'application';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * VIEW DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want to move the view directory out of the application
 * directory, set the path to it here. The directory can be renamed
 * and relocated anywhere on your server. If blank, it will default
 * to the standard location inside your application directory.
 * If you do move this, use an absolute (full) server path.
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $view_folder = '';


/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here. For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT: If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller. Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 */
    // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" directory.  Leave blank
    // if your controller is not in a sub-directory within the "controllers" one
    // $routing['directory'] = '';

    // The controller class file name.  Example:  mycontroller
    // $routing['controller'] = '';

    // The controller function you wish to be called.
    // $routing['function'] = '';


/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 */
    // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item';



// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS.  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    else
    {
        // Ensure there's a trailing slash
        $system_path = strtr(
            rtrim($system_path, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // Path to the system directory
    define('BASEPATH', $system_path);

    // Path to the front controller (this file) directory
    define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    // Name of the "system" directory
    define('SYSDIR', basename(BASEPATH));

    // The path to the "application" directory
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $application_folder = $_temp;
        }
        else
        {
            $application_folder = strtr(
                rtrim($application_folder, '/\\'),
                '/\\',
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            );
        }
    }
    elseif (is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $application_folder = BASEPATH.strtr(
            trim($application_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    // The path to the "views" directory
    if ( ! isset($view_folder[0]) && is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
    }
    elseif (is_dir($view_folder))
    {
        if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $view_folder = $_temp;
        }
        else
        {
            $view_folder = strtr(
                rtrim($view_folder, '/\\'),
                '/\\',
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            );
        }
    }
    elseif (is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $view_folder = APPPATH.strtr(
            trim($view_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

    define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

HomeResources.js

```
angular.module('app.home').factory('HomeResources', function ($http, $q, APP_CONFIG, httpApiConfig) {
    var dfd = $q.defer();

    return {
        // get_Admins: $resource(APP_CONFIG.apiRootUrl + "/Admin/adminApi", {}, {
        //     'query': { method: 'get', isArray: true },
        //     'add': { method: 'POST', url: apiUrl.url + '/Admin/adminApi/create', isArray: true },
        //     'delete': { method: 'POST', url: apiUrl.url + '/Admin/adminApi/delete' },
        //     'update': { method: 'POST', url: apiUrl.url + '/Admin/adminApi/update' }
        // }),
        getPosts: function () {
            var UPDATE_URL = APP_CONFIG.apiRootUrl + "/Advertisement/allposts";
            return $http.get(UPDATE_URL, httpApiConfig);
        },

        getCategories: function () {
            var UPDATE_URL = APP_CONFIG.apiRootUrl + "/Modules/allCategory";
            return $http.get(UPDATE_URL, httpApiConfig);
        },

        // banners: function () {
        //     var BANNERS_URL = APP_CONFIG.apiRootUrl + "/Profile/bannerList";
        //     return $http.get(BANNERS_URL);
        // },

    }
});
```

My query is in this `HomeResources.js` .

I do console log and `APP_CONFIG.apiRootUrl` is referring to the `index.php` shown above.

`httpApiConfig` is referring to the code in `app.js`.

My query is what does this line do `return $http.get(UPDATE_URL, httpApiConfig)`. I guess it is trying to read data from SQL database.

Comment: Start by reading the [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Also read up on how ajax (which is what $http does) works. Study some angular tutorials also...the answers for this are all easily researched

Comment: @charlietfl I know $http get post. These three files are extracting data from the database. I am expecting somebody can show me how these three files extract the data. For example, UPDATE_URL = ../api/index.php/Modules/allCategory is referring to the index.php above. What does index.php do? I can't figure out what functions in index.php do. How can I understand it? What does this httpApiConfig do?

Comment: `httpApiConfig ` is for the `$http` config object as noted in $http docs. They simply set it as a constant so it could be injected anywhere in the app. It's a strange way to handle the defaults though

Comment: index.php is simply the main codeigniter file that starts the whole CI framework app. You shouldn't have to do anything with that after it is configured for initial install.Most of what you do within codeigniter would be done in controller, model and view files as per codeigniter docs. Their documentation is also very good and easy to navigate

Comment: @charlietfl I need to read codeigniter.

Comment: @charlietfl thanks. After reading codeigniter, all I want to know are inside that folder.

Comment: no idea if that is a question or what it means